# Remove gray horizontal line between titlebar with material theme on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, themes

I show in the image below a screenshot using Emacs 29.1 on Mac OS X with the material theme and the ﻿﻿https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus port. You can see that there's a gray line drawn between the title bar and the buffer. This seems to only exist with this theme (i.e., other dark themes don't draw this line) and on this particular Emacs' port (e.g., the railwaycat port doesn't have this issue). Any ideas how I could remove this? I know it's inconsequential to work, but visually it's annoying.

[image]

Comment: Check (C-h v) the variable ```default-frame-alist``` and see if you have the item ```ns-transparent-titlebar``` set to t.

Comment: it says ` (ns-transparent-titlebar . t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is part of internal border; to remove it,
after loading the `material-theme` add the following line to your configuration

```lisp
(set-frame-parameter nil 'internal-border-width 0)
```